# Upcrossing lemma and subharmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, martingales, harmonic-functions

I have been studying the upcrossing lemma for submartingales, which asserts that if $X_n$ is a non negative submartingale, and $
\lambda>0$ then if we denote by $U_n$ the number of $[0,\lambda]$-upcrossings of the martingale $X_n$ before time $n$ it holds that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E} U_n \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}X_n}{\lambda}, \quad n=1,2,\dots
\end{equation*}
To define rigorusly an upcrossing let
\begin{equation*}
S_{1}=\min\{k:X_k = 0\}, \quad T_1 = \min\{ k>S_1 : X_k \geq \lambda \}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
S_{i+1}=\min\{ k >T_i : X_k = 0 \} \quad T_i = \min \{ k> S_{i+1} : X_k \geq \lambda \}.
\end{equation*}
The number of upcrossings $U_n$ before time $n$ is
\begin{equation*} 
U_n = \max\{ j: T_j \leq n \}.
\end{equation*}

This is the key lemma for proving the almost sure convergence of uniformly integrable martingales. I was wandering if there exist a counterpart of this lemma for non negative subharmonic functions. Let $f$ be a non negative subharmonic function in an open set containing the closed unit disc and for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and lets say that $f$ has more than $N \in \mathbb{N}$,  $[0,\lambda] $-upcrossings in the direction $\theta$ if there exist $0\leq x_1<y_1<x_2<y_2<\dots<x_N<y_N<1$ such that $f(x_ie^{i\theta})=0, f(y_ie^{i\theta})\geq \lambda $. Let $ U(\theta) $ be the maximum number $N$ such that $f$ has more than $N$ upcrossings in the direction $\theta$.

Is it possible to prove an estimate of the form
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} U(\theta) d\theta \leq \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{i\theta}) d\theta.  
\end{equation*}

I have not verified this even for simple examples so it might be blatantly false. In that case is there a "correct version of this" ?